# Finding a repeated values in Excel with different locations in an Excel using python

Tags: python, excel

I have an Excel sheet with a value called "TX_DROP" which is a title with 80 to 90 row below it (let's call these rows X). This title repeats again in the file after these 80-90 rows in a different column but with a different number of columns and rows, so I cannot predict the column and row where "TX_Drop" appears in each repeat.

I want to write a Python script to read all TX_Drops from this file.

Example of a file:

```
Granularity         ETH_RX  RX_DROP TX_DROP
15 Min                  2      8      3
15 Min                  0      6      12
15 Min                  11     5      0
15 Min                  1      5      4

Granularity         ETH_RX  TX_DROP RX_DROP
15 Min                  0      1      0
15 Min                  0      0      4
15 Min                  12     11     8
15 Min                  90     23     9

Granularity        TX_DROP  ETH_RX  RX_DROP ETH_TX
15 Min                  30     0      0      10
15 Min                  4      0      0      11
15 Min                  7      0      0      5
15 Min                  8      0      0      3
```

I want to read all TX_DROPs with python in this file, as follows:

```
TX_DROP
  3
  12
  0
  4
  1
  0
  11
  23
  30
  4
  7
  8
```

Thanks

Comment: So, this is not an excel problem then - why tag excel?

Comment: @pnuts So, what that means is, sadly, I can use the excel tag as I want to help with excel based questions but may only find other programs issues / questions since those programs happen to want to open / read an excel file - loosing some functionality / control here aren't we?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using xlrd:

http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

The usage is simple, you just need to read your data:

```
import xlrd

wk = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xslx')
```

if you can access your sheet by index:

```
sheet = wk.sheet_by_index(0)
```

you can get a row:

```
row = sheet.row(0)
```

And you can get a specific cell:

```
data = sheet.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=0)
```

Also now, to have the output that you desire, you need to build your own algorithm.

I would iterate on the element of the first column. If the data match 'Granularity', I would iterate on the row until the name match 'TX_DROP'.
Then I would iterate on the row under this column, until I get an empty cell.

This would produce your expected output.

Comment: My Problem is that i dont know the index of the TX_DROP_RATIO cell.

Comment: But you know that this Cell is on the same line as 'Granularity'. And you know that 'Granularity' is in the first column. You can use these informations to deduce the position of 'TX_DROP'

Comment: Getting more and more complicated!!, just simply how to do that?

Comment: Could you please tell how to iterate base on the  'Granularity' until i get "TX_DROP" ?

Comment: ok, distance to the 'Granularity' is not fixed sometimes it changes, what about this one?

Answer (score -1):

ok this is what i've get so far:

```
import csv
import time
search_string = 'TX_DROP_RATIO'

with open('data.csv' , 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row == search_string:
            print(row)

csvfile.close()
```

i Decided to go for CSV file.

but i get no output from my code.(cause it's incomplete)

Comment: I know my file contains at least 365 rows containing column named: "TX_DROP_RATIO"

Comment: UPDATE: each "TX_DROP..." occurs 8 rows later after last data of the previous TX_DROP